# Postgresql query using multiple WHERE conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am wondering if there is a simple / smart way to pass a query to a Postgresql database. I have a database whose headers look something like this:

```
measurementPointID | parameterA | parameterB | measurement | measurementTIME
```

There are some dozens of records within the database.

I would like to pass a query that retrieves data only for a set of `measurementPointID`'s. There are several dozens of thousands of `measurementPointID`'s values that I need to retrieve and I have all of these available in, for example, an CSV file.

The query should do a `GROUP BY measurementTIME` and `ORDER BY measurementTIME` as well. One detail is that if the measurement is zero (measurement = 0) there is no row corresponding to the `measurementPointID` at all.

Am I trying to do something too complicated or in a stupid way?

Comment: Put the measurementPointID values you want in a temp table and INNER JOIN?

Comment: Thanks, Alex! As you can see I am quite the beginner :) ... I will read into this advice you are giving! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Post sample data and desired result

Comment: Will do, @ClodoaldoNeto ... let me work on it...